# MySQL Stored Procedure Not Inserting Data - No Errors

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I cannot figure out why my MySQL stored procedure is not inserting data to the two tables. My script does execute, but the row count is 0 and the tables do not have the new data. Here is my stored procedure for the insert:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_CreateAthlete`(IN athleteID int(11), IN athleteName varchar(100), IN athleteSurname varchar(100), IN emailAddress varchar(150), IN userName varchar(100), IN athletePassword varchar(100), IN securityQuestion varchar(200), IN securityAnswer varchar(100), IN athleteCountry varchar(100), IN dateOfBirth varchar(30), IN userType varchar(100))
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
END;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
END;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO iBalekaDB.user (UserID, `Name`, Surname, EmailAddress, Country, UserType, DateOfBirth) 
VALUES (athleteID, athleteName, athleteSurname, emailAddress, athleteCountry, userType, dateOfBirth);

INSERT INTO iBalekaDB.usercredential (UserName, `Password`, SecurityQuestion, UserID, SecurityAnswer)
VALUES (userName, enteredPassword, securityQuestion, athleteID, securityAnswer);
COMMIT;
END
```

This is the PHP script which is supposed to insert the data to the database. Table usercredential has a foreign key on UserID - this is from the user table.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once("db_connection.php");

$athleteID = $_POST['AthleteID'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$country = $_POST['Country'];
$dateOfBirth = $_POST['DateOfBirth'];
$emailAddress = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
$userName = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
$securityQuestion = $_POST['SecurityQuestion'];
$securityAnswer = $_POST['SecurityAnswer'];
$type = "A";

$registrationArray;

if (isset($athleteID, $name, $surname, $country, $dateOfBirth, $emailAddress, $userName, $password, $securityQuestion, $securityAnswer)) {

    $checkAthlete = $connectionObject->prepare("CALL sp_CheckAthleteRegistration(?,?)");
    $checkAthlete->bindParam(1, $athleteID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $checkAthlete->bindParam(2, $emailAddress, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $checkAthlete->execute();
    if ($checkAthlete->rowCount() > 0) {
        $msg = array('error' => array('message', 'The email address you tried using has been used'));
        echo json_encode($msg);
        $checkAthlete->closeCursor();
    } else {
        $checkAthlete->closeCursor();

        $checkAthleteUsername = $connectionObject->prepare("CALL sp_CheckUsername(?,?)");
        $checkAthleteUsername->bindParam(1, $athleteID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $checkAthleteUsername->bindParam(2, $userName, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $checkAthleteUsername->execute();
        if ($checkAthleteUsername->rowCount() > 0) {
            $errMsg = array('error' => array('message', 'The username you tried registering has already been used'));
            echo json_encode($errMsg);
        } else {
            $checkAthleteUsername->closeCursor();

            $insertAthlete = $connectionObject->prepare("CALL sp_CreateAthlete(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(1, $athleteID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(2, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(3, $surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(4, $emailAddress, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(5, $userName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(6, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(7, $securityQuestion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(8, $securityAnswer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(9, $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(10, $dateOfBirth, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $insertAthlete->bindParam(11, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $insertAthlete->execute();
            if ($insertAthlete->rowCount() > 0) {
                $insMsg = array('success' => array('message', 'You have successfully registered for an account with iBaleka'));
                echo json_encode($insMsg);
            } else {
                $regerrrMsg = array('error' => array('message', 'An error occurred while registering for the system. Please try again'));
                echo json_encode($regerrrMsg);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    $registrationArray = array("error" => array("message", "Please ensure all fields have data"));
}
```

Comment: Did you tried it within  your MySQL is it working well over there?

Comment: Like this abandoned question you never responded to earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38294402 . And all those non-accepted answers. you guys can have it.

Comment: Yeah it was like that one. I didnt add the PHP stuff in that question.

Comment: Tried executing it with dbForge - the stored procedure does execute, however no rows are inserted.